# ColdFusion HELP Pages not Updating: My CF pages are still pointing to the original folder of my application

Tags: coldfusion

I have an existing ColdFusion application in my server. What I needed is a duplicate of that application. What I did was copy the entire folder of the original application and put it into another folder.

I already edited the Application.cfm and the links across all the pages in my copy. However, `.../indexc.cfm?page=a_app_checklist` - in this case, the a_app_checklist is not being updated even if I changed everything on my server `/Copy/pages/app/a_app_checklist.cfm`
I tried to upload the updated `a_app_checklist.cfm` on the original application and from there, it was updated. What should I do because I want my copy of the application to be a stand-alone from the original application.

Here is a part of my Application.cfm code:

```
<cfapplication name="Applicationv2" sessionmanagement="yes" setclientcookies="yes" sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(00,00,30,00)#" 
               applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(00,01,00,00)#" clientstorage="cookie" loginstorage="session">


<cfparam name="Url.page" default="a_main_index">
<cfparam name="Url.formpage" default="">
<cfparam name="Url.resetAppCache" default="">

<!--- Set the Application variables if they aren't defined. --->
<cfset app_is_initialized = False>
<cflock scope="application" type="readonly" timeout="5">
   <cfset app_is_initialized = IsDefined("Application.initialized")>
</cflock>
<cfif not app_is_initialized>
   <cflock scope="application" type="exclusive" timeout=10>
      <cfif not IsDefined("Application.initialized")>
         <!--- Do initializations --->
         <cfset Application.StudentDB = "DB">
         <cfset Application.Url = "/CopyOfApplication/">
         <cfset Application.NSUrl = "/CopyOfApplication/">
         <cfset Application.EmailLocation = "/CopyOfApplication/pages/email/">
         <cfset Application.userfilespath = "/web_assets/UserFiles/">
         <cfset Application.UnauthorizedFileExtentions = "ade,adp,asx,bas,chm,cmd,cpl,crt,dbx,exe,hlp,com,hta,inf,ins,isp,jse,lnk,mda,mde,mdz,mht,msc,msi,msp,mst,nch,pcd,prf,reg,scf,scr,sct,shb,shs,url,tmp,pif,dll,vb,vbs">
         <cfset Application.ReportPage = "report.cfm">
         <cfset Application.PrintPage = "print.cfm">
         <!---Puts an instance of the user.cfc and system.cfc in the application scope. All pages can use it. --->
            <cfobject type="component" name="Application.System" component="application.system">
         <cfset Application.initialized = "yes">
      </cfif>
   </cflock>
    <cfscript>
        Application.System.LogActivity("Name","IP","Application scope variables initialized.");
    </cfscript>
</cfif>
```

Like I said, the "page" part in the URL are the only ones that are not being updated. Does it mean I have problems with my URL.Page initialization?

Please let me know if you need additional code. I appreciate any input about this question. Thank you in advance! I am still learning ColdFusion and I will appreciate it if you will help me understand what I need to know!

Comment: Sounds like one or more links are still pointing to the old directory. However, that is about all we can say without seeing some code or a concrete example.

Comment: First things first... why are you duplicating the site? Can you pls update the question to explain the reason you're undertaking this exercise.